# How can I automatically recheck a checkbox that has been unchecked using angular

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have a checkbox that a user can uncheck or check.
when the user unchecks it, I want to automatically check it using angular

I'm using angular 7.

template code:

```
  type="checkbox"
  [(ngModel)]="CheckBoxValue"
  (ngModelChange)="onChangeCheckBox(CheckBoxValue)"/>
```

component event to recheck if unchecked:

```
  public onChangeCheckBox(value: boolean): void {
    if (!value) {
      this._checkBoxValue = true;
      console.log("I have been there");
    }
  }
```

here s link to my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgud2c

You may Ask what do I want to do this?  My original question was more complex.
I have tried my best to simplify it. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044643/cant-uncheck-checkbox-using-angular)

Comment: Isn't this basically a radio button?

Comment: Yes @Selkie, I wanted the exact behavior of a radio button. But I was wondering why checking the checkbox programmatically does not work using angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use a radio button, but if you can't for whatever reason, you could use a hacky `setTimeout` to achieve your goal:

```
public onChangeCheckBox(value: boolean): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
       this._checkBoxValue = true;
    });
}
```